# How to get CPU & Memory usage for a Python FastAPI script on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

I'm running a FastAPI script on Google App Engine, is there a way to get the CPU & Memory usage for a single request made? I'm trying to calculate how many requests a single instance can take.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't and that is the wrong thing to measure anyway.

You want to run load testing where you have a script that does X requests/second to your website over a period of time to see what your website can handle.